# Fiber sequence, a group and an $n$-group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, fibration

Given a short exact sequence
$$
1 \to B\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{G} \to O(n) \to 1
$$
and the fiber sequence:
$$
B^2\mathbb{Z}_2 \to B\mathbb{G} \to BO(n),
$$
classified by $\beta \in H^3(BO(n), \mathbb{Z}_2)=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$.

> **Question**: Would you call the $\mathbb{G}$ (there are $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ choices), a group or 2-group, or both?
>
> - Why is $\mathbb{G}$ a group? What is the perspective?
> - Why is $\mathbb{G}$ a 2-group? What is the perspective?

Comment: I would call $\mathbb{G}$ a group. The short exact sequence is equivalent to a crossed module, and hence $2$-group, but without the extra data $\mathbb{G}$ is a just a group. Also, you should probably only consider *strict* 2-groups in such a situation.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong, I meant to ask $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2 \to B\mathbb{G} \to BO(n).$

Comment: What makes you think there are $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ choices for $\mathbb{G}$? Note that $H^3(BO(n);\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is generated by $w_1^3$, $w_1w_2$ and $w_3$ (assuming $n\geq3$) but $\Omega w_1^3\simeq\ast\simeq \Omega(w_1w_2)$, so as you have defined it there are multiple homotopy types for $B\mathbb{G}$ that all loop to the same space.